# Issue reading user Input

Tags: c#

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var numTestCases = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int l=0;l<numTestCases;l++)
        {
            var numMember = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            var ele = Console.ReadLine();
            var gteammember = ele.Trim().Split(' ').ToList();
            var oppTeamMember = Console.ReadLine().Trim().Split(' ').ToList();
            Dictionary<int, long> dict = new Dictionary<int, long>();
            int Count = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < oppTeamMember.Count; k++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < gteammember.Count; j++)
                {
                    var newoppTeamMember = Convert.ToInt64(oppTeamMember[k]);
                    var newgteammember = Convert.ToInt64(gteammember[j]);
                    if (newoppTeamMember < newgteammember)
                    {
                        dict.Add(j, newgteammember);
                    }
                }
                if (dict.Count > 0)
                {
                    var keyR = dict.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value).First();
                    Count++;
                    gteammember.RemoveAt(keyR.Key);
                    dict.Clear();
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(Count);

        }

    }
```

I have a user input like

[image]

but it reads only half the number from 72 number user inputs. can someone please tell me the issue or any other way to solve this issue. I have checked the above code it works fine for small input eg 10,20 etc

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?  You seem to be adding to the dictionary any gteammember that is lower than any of the oppteammember entries.  This means the dictionary count will be heavily based on your data and not a fixed amount.  You are also editing the gteammember list inside the for loop which is not good practice

Comment: The code is fine.i want to know why it is not reading the 72  space separated values in above code. Eg check var ele = Console.ReadLine(); with sample input.

Comment: It's impossible to say without having the document itself. But rest assured, if the program is behaving differently than you expect, you've done something wrong. Either you're not providing the input in the way you think you are, or you're not reading it in the way you think you are. This would be a great time to familiarize yourself with the Visual Studio debugger.